# How to add different sizes of a product in Mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using MongoDb and Mongoose to create a model for a practice e-commerce site. Here is what I have so far for my Product model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',{
  imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, required: true}
});
```

My question is say I have a shirt which has different size options such as S, M, and L. What is the best way to add this? Also, if I include inventory tracking how would I keep track of all sizes? Thanks in advance and any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do this, but the easiest is probably via some sub-schema.  For example you could create something like:

```
const ProductVariant = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,  // If you're certain this will only ever be sizes, you could make it an enum
  inventory: Number
});
```

Then in your product definition:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',{
  imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, required: true},
  variants: [ProductVariant]
});
```

If you wanted, you could also hook in some logic to ensure that the variant names were unique per product, etc, but this is a basic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> I think this can be a better way

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',{
imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
title: {type: String, required: true},
description: {type: String, required: true},
price: {type: Number, required: true},
size:{type:String, enum:["S","M","L"]}
});
```

Creating Sub Schema's are efficient but here just for one parameter, it's useless.

Comment: This is what I did, however, you can't do this if you want to keep track of the count of each of the sizes. If someone buys a size medium, you'll need to change its count. And if you have a cart system, you need to check if the quantity of that item is less than the amount left in stock.